# How to POST from JS or node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, httprequest

I want to do the following `POST` command from my JS or node.js file.

terminal.zsh

```
curl -L --data-binary @data/scrape.csv https://script.google.com/macros/s/#/exec
```

I can successfully write my .csv file from my node.js file with the following code.

node.js

```
const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv');
const itemsAsCsv = new ObjectsToCsv(formattedItems);
itemsAsCsv.toDisk(filePathCsv, { allColumns: true, });
```

I have unsuccessfully tried the following. I expect to see the data hit my API but instead I see no data.

node.js

```
const request = require('request');
request({
  method: 'POST',
  preambleCRLF: true,
  postambleCRLF: true,
  uri: postUrl,
  multipart: {
    chunked: false,
    data,
  },
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run your `curl` command with the `-v` flag to see the request headers. FYI, it is not creating a multipart request. When I execute that command, it sends a regular `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request with the CSV data as the request body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to upload a CSV file to Web Apps of Google Apps Script using Node.js.

  - From the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/#/exec`, I could understand that you are using Web Apps of Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, at Web Apps of Google Apps Script, even when `multipart/form-data` or `multipart/related` are used, the received data cannot be parsed. So in this case, as a workaround, the CSV data is send as data.

#### Modified script:

When your script of Node.js is modified, how about the following modification? Before you use this script, please set the URL of Web Apps and the filename of the file.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");
request(
  {
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec", // Please set this.
    method: "POST",
    body: fs.createReadStream("./sample.csv"), // Please set this.
    followAllRedirects: true
  },
  function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    // console.log(res);
    console.log(body);
  }
);
```

- In this modified script, it supposes that the CSV file is uploaded as a sample. The sample CSV filename is `sample.csv`.
- When you run this script, the CSV file is uploaded to Web Apps.
- `followAllRedirects` is the redirect. The default value is `false`. So `true` is set. This is required to access to Web Apps of Google Apps Script.
- If you want to upload an object like `data = { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }`, please modify `body: fs.createReadStream("./sample.csv"),` to `body: JSON.stringify(data),`. By this, the value can be retrieved and parsed with `JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)` at `doPost(e)`.

#### Sample script of Web Apps:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(e.postData.contents);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.appendRow([JSON.stringify(e)]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}
```

- By above script, when the sample Node.js script is run, `sample.csv` is uploaded, and the uploaded data is parsed by `Utilities.parseCsv()`. Then, the parsed values are put to the sheet `Sheet1` of the active Spreadsheet.
- If the delimiter is not `,`, please set it as `parseCsv(csv, delimiter)`.

#### Sample situation:

When the following CSV file (`sample.csv`) is uploaded to the above Web Apps with above Node.js script,

```
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
a5,b5,c5,d5,e5
a6,b6,c6,d6,e6
a7,b7,c7,d7,e7
a8,b8,c8,d8,e8
a9,b9,c9,d9,e9
a10,b10,c10,d10,e10
```

the following event object can be retrieved. So the CSV data can be parsed by `Utilities.parseCsv(e.postData.contents)`.

```
{
  "parameter": {},
  "contextPath": "",
  "contentLength": 165,
  "queryString": "",
  "parameters": {},
  "postData": {
    "type": "text/csv",
    "length": 165,
    "contents": "a1,b1,c1,d1,e1\r\na2,b2,c2,d2,e2\r\na3,b3,c3,d3,e3\r\na4,b4,c4,d4,e4\r\na5,b5,c5,d5,e5\r\na6,b6,c6,d6,e6\r\na7,b7,c7,d7,e7\r\na8,b8,c8,d8,e8\r\na9,b9,c9,d9,e9\r\na10,b10,c10,d10,e10\r\n",
    "name": "postData"
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)
- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.